# MySQL Query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I do the equivalent in Eloquent (i.e. `Model::where(...)->join(...)`?:

```
DB::select('SELECT users.id, users.username
        FROM users, teams, teams AS teams2
        WHERE users.team_id = teams2.id
        AND teams.id = ?
        AND teams2.l BETWEEN teams.l AND teams.r', [$id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

```
$team = Team::find($id);
$users = User::join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'users.team_id')
             ->whereBetween('teams.l', [$team->l, $team->r])
             ->get(['users.id', 'users.username']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work, it just gives me the members of the team with $id, and not the team with $id and all members of child teams.

Comment: I assume because all teams in 'teams.l BETWEEN teams.l AND teams.r' must have id $id.

Comment: Getting: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereBetween() must be of the type array, object given

Comment: Updated, call toArray() after values().