# Convert Mysql query to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I would to convert mysql query to laravel query.

MySQL:

```
select product_id as urun from product_features 
   where feature_id = 58 
      or feature_id = 100 
      or (feature_id = 52 or feature_id = 48 or feature_id = 53)      
   group by product_id having(count(product_id)>2)
```

Edit: I can not enclose 'or' expressions in parentheses.

Comment: Have you got models & relationships set up correctly?

Comment: May be of help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714718/mysql-query-in-laravel-eloquent

Comment: Thank you. But I can not enclose 'or' expressions in parentheses.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ . Also, when you clicked to create this post, the button said "Ask Question". Since when was "I want" a question or a problem? We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Comment: It's a simple post that wasn't phrased in the best manner, sure an edit should be made, but hell, there's no reason knockout a new user.

Comment: @snh I'm evidently not the only person who agrees. My beef is - it wasn't a question, it was a demand for a solution, posted with no evidence of the OP having made any effort at all to research it. This is especially annoying when, as one of the answers pointed out, there's ample documentation and examples online available already which would at least allow someone to try it out. if you want to spend your free time spoon-feeding ppl who give the impression their time is more valuable than yours, go ahead. I'd rather help someone out who'd tried their best first. SO is not (Free)Rent-A-Coder.

Comment: "If you want to spend your free time spoon-feeding ppl who give the impression their time is more valuable than yours, go ahead." Yet you have time to provide fat lip to new users and existing users instead. Makes sense, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @snh It takes 10 seconds max to write a comment. OTOH, time to research, test (or at least validate) the code for a correct answer, from scratch? Anyway I'm not against new users who want to ask good questions. This is not a good question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, or  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ or https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Avoid-Being-an-Internet-Troll

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I can not enclose 'or' expressions in parentheses.

Sure you can. :-)

What you'll want to look at is Laravel's [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) functionality.

```
$query->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('foo', 'bar')
          ->orWhere('foo', 'not-bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
$query = DB::table('product_features')->where('feature_id', 52)->orWhere('feature_id', 48)->orWhere('feature_id', 53)->
    orWhere('feature_id', 100)->orWhere('feature_id', 58)->
    select('product_id')->groupBy('product_id')->havingRaw("count(product_id) > 2")->get();
```

Comment: While this will work in your particular case, this won't produce the parenthesis, which will cause issues in more complicated queries. See my answer for how you'd do parenthetical sections of a query.

Comment: I will do as you say. Thank you.